# Weird polarity switching in home inverter wiring

Tags: inverter, mains

So I have a Backup Inverter installed in my house, it was installed when I wasn't around. Now I need to add an inverter line to a board that didn't had it before. To do this I generally tap the (live/phase) wire from the inverter output and run a wire to that board. But the problem is when the mains supply is ON the inverter's output along with the neutral wire of mains are working (those two wires are making the bulb glow) but when the mains is OFF then the inverter's live coupled with the live of mains works. What i don't understand is why is the polarity switching like this? And how should I connect the board so that I would get continues power in that board irrespective of mains being present or not?

What I'd guess is that this Inverter configuration is not simply a common neutral one but something else.

Comment: Define what you mean by "works with".

Comment: @SimonB I can run my appliances but those two wires.

Comment: Can you include a schematic / wiring diagram? Also note: it sounds like this is illegal according to the electrical code, since you should bring a neutral wire as well as a live wire. (neutrals and lives should always be together)

Comment: @user253751 Will try to post it if possible. Btw can you still guess whats going on? , Ignoring the legality as I am not aware of Indian Wiring Standards.

Comment: No, I can't tell you what's going on since I can't understand how it's wired. Btw, I don't care whether *your* house follows the standard. I am just telling you in case you didn't know.